# Menu bar not shown when mouse on top of screen in full screen mode

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, menu-bar

Disclaimer: I am rather new to macOS.

In full-screen mode, the menu bar is hidden and should show up when the mouse pointer is moved to the top edge of the screen. This stopped working today. No matter how hard I smash the little pointer at the top edge of the screen, the menu will not show up. Uh, it just dawns on me, that the window title bar also does not show up. The only way to leave full-screen mode is via ctrl-command-f.

When I configure the menu bar to be automatically hiding and showing it works in normal window mode, but still not in full-screen mode.
Is this some kind of configuration that I activated accidentally (still trying to find my way around the system)?

- Hardware: MacBook Pro 16"
- OS: macOS 10.15.4
- Apps "manipulating" the menu bar: Dozer and Battery Monitor

Any ideas?

Comment: **1** which app is being used ? it should not happen in all apps. **2** Also, sometimes I have to keep moving my finger up even if pointer touches the top. **3** as an alternative, you can use view menu of most apps to remove clutter & use apps normally. **4** esc key should also bring you out of the full screen, in most apps.  be careful to not lose any work

Comment: 1. It happens with all apps (I tried several). 2. I keep moving up and up and up... 3. While true, this does not solve the root problem. macOS should not behave like this in the first place. 4. Same as 3.

Comment: I did the unthinkable and rebooted /gasp/. Now it works again. Weird.